# Linux Mint 18.3 Synaptic - Opera - Could not resolve host

Tags: networking, linux-mint, synaptic, opera

Using Linux Mint 18.3 on Dell XPS 15 laptop.

My update manager is having some issues, I am having difficult time troubleshooting it.

It complains that:

```
Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.comSome index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can in fact ping `deb.opera.com`

Also, I can navigate to `https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/` using opera, and I do see there is an `InRelease` file.

What is going on?  How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - thx - how can I ensure that it is for mint?

Comment: This seems a DNS issue. Try to use 8.8.8.8 as DNS.